# 0 byte files not visible in view in modern experience

Tags: modern-experience, classic-experience

I've encountered an issue with modern experience.
When I have uploaded files with 0 byte size in modern experience they are not visible in view.
When I change experience to classic files are visible.
Any idea if this can be fixed?